# conditional syntax for excluding pages wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

Trying to exclude a piece of code from running on certain pages. I would like to do something like the following, but this syntax isn't correct.

```
<?php 
if (!is_page('Blog') || $post->post_parent=="19")) { 
    <?php breadcrumbs(); ?>
} else {}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First error is -  PHP tag was not closed.
And second is - there should be opening of PHP tag before else condition.

try this

```
<?php if (!is_page('Blog') || $post->post_parent=="19")) { ?>
    <?php breadcrumbs(); ?>
<?php  } else {
          //   
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory text in order to make this a potentially useful answer.

Comment: It would be great if you could explain *why* his syntax was wrong and why it needs to be changed to that in your answer - this kind of explanation is useful for others who come to the site looking for answers to similar questions - thanks.

Comment: Excellent - thanks for making this a much better answer - +1 !